# Database design: Users with roles and profiles with fields for each role

Tags: sql, database, profile

I want to design a database with the following requirements, but I'm having problems.

I have 3 types of users: Doctors, Registered Users, and Administrators. In the future I may add other types of users. Each of these user types has different profile fields. For example, Registered Users should have (`Username`, `Password`, `Email`, `FirstName`, and `LastName`). Also Doctors have the previous fields but also should have extra fields (`PhoneNumber`, `WorkPlace`, `Country`, `State`, `City`, ...). These fields may be different for other user types. Some fields are common to every user type, and some aren't.

I think I need two tables: Users, And Roles.

```
Users Table
============
UserID INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT
Username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
Password VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
Email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
FirstName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
LastName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
RoleID INT NOT NULL                   //This is the foreign key

Roles Table:
=============
RoleID INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT
RoleName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
```

But how can I implement different profile fields for different user types?

Comment: There are many ways to design what you describe. It is a matter of personal preference mostly. One way would be having a `Users` table and a `Doctors` table that would inherit `Users`. In that way a Doctor would inherit all fields of `Users` and also have the Doctor specific fields from the `Doctors` table.

Comment: I need to design database flexible. In future i may add other user types, For example what happens if I add a StoreManager user type?

Comment: Scalability is the second reason you would choose one way over the other to design your database. If you choose to implement it with what I suggested, that is inheritance, in order to add another type of user you would need to design another table and that table would again inherit from `users`, if it needs to include the specific fields of the `users` table.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need a table for user (what you have) and 3 more tables (table inheritance) for Doctors, Registered Users, and Administrators which will have the same `id` (`OneToOne` relationship) with specific columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can create 3 more tables for Doctors, RegisteredUsers, and Administrator profiles.

```
Doctors
==========
UserID INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
PhoneNumber,
WorkPlace,
Country,
State,
City,
FOREIGN KEY (UserID) REFERENCES Users(UserID)

RegisteredUsers
=================
UserID INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
Photo,
Address,
bla bla.....
FOREIGN KEY (UserID) REFERENCES Users(UserID)

Administrators
================
UserID INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
.....
.....
FOREIGN KEY (UserID) REFERENCES Users(UserID)
```